# Azure DevOps board won't let me change the time/date format

Tags: datetime, azure-devops, user-profile

I have an Azure DevOps board and it has some user stories. I want to change the Date/Time format but it won't let me change the time/date format from MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY.
[image]

I tried by changing format from user settings. But no luck. Can you please help me to sort this out. Thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: Referred this. But still same issue, 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-your-preferences?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure DevOps, the format of the work item time/date will depend on the language in your browser.

To change the Work item time format, you need to change the language in your Browser.

For example: **Chrome Settings -> Advanced -> Languages -> Set the preference language**.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. This was the issue and resolved by changing the date/ time format on browser.

Comment: This is not true any longer, at least not for the iteration dates in Project Settings - Team Configuration. I have MM/DD/YYYY in Azure Devops. But the language i have set in Chrome have YYYY-MM-DD as default.  
Even changing the regional setting in https://portal.azure.com/#settings did not change the date in Azure Devops. 
"Time and Locale" in the Azure Devops profile settings are also set to yyyy-MM-dd.